# Switch toggle custom stay fixed in Datatable using laravel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a toggle switch custom to my Datatable. I'm using the following code from Bootstrap inside my datatable:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1" name="example">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1">Toggle me</label>
</div>
```

I get the following result:

[image]

The problem is when I try to switch or activate the toggle, just the first row changes. But for the other rows, when I try to switch, nothing occurs; the custom toggle switch stays fixed.

**EDIT 1**

My Controller:

```js
function getdata(Request $request) {
  if (request() - > ajax()) {
    return datatables() - > of (Casting::latest() - > get()) -
      > addColumn('action', function($data) {
        $button = '<table><tr><td>';
        $button. = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data - > id.
        '" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
        $button. = '</td><td>';
        $button. = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
        $button. = '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1" name="status"';

        if ($data - > status == 1) {
          $button. = 'checked';
        }

        $button. = '> <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1"></label></div>';
        $button. = '</td></tr></table>';
        return $button;
      }) -
      > rawColumns(['action']) -
      > make(true);
  }
  return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

I added the column in the Controller.

My Script:

```js
$('#datatableRows').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns: [
    {
      data: 'casting_photo',
      name: 'casting_photo',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data + " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
      },
      orderable: false
    },
    {
      data: 'casting_name',
      name: 'casting_name',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
      }
    },
    {
      data: 'casting_cin',
      name: 'casting_cin'
    },
    {
      data: 'casting_phone',
      name: 'casting_phone'
    },

    {
      data: 'action',
      name: 'action',
      orderable: false
    }
  ]
});
```

**EDIT 2**

```js
$('#datatableRows').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns: [
    {
      data: 'casting_photo',
      name: 'casting_photo',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data + " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
      },
      orderable: false
    },
    {
      data: 'casting_name',
      name: 'casting_name',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
      }
    },
    {
      data: 'casting_cin',
      name: 'casting_cin'
    },
    {
      data: 'status',
      name: 'status',
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return "<div class='custom-control custom-switch'><input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id='switch1' name='status' value =" + data + "><label class='custom-control-label' for='switch1'></label></div>";
      }
    },
    {
      data: 'action',
      name: 'action',
      orderable: false
    }
  ]
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the code for "other rows"? Do you have unique `id` attribute and matching `for` attribute on each row?

Comment: @miken32 please check my EDIT

Comment: Yeah you are reusing `switch1` over and over again. Also I would strongly recommend not doing the HTML on the server side at all, and use the column [`render` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) instead (same thing you do for `casting_photo` and `casting_name`.)

Comment: please can you explain more how can I do that

Comment: I'm not sure how much more clearly I can say it. You're reusing "switch1" as an ID. Don't do it. ID must be unique in the document.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: Can you make this runnable to show that behaviour ?

Comment: @Swati , how can I make it runnable? , I'm still a beginner

Comment: With dummy datas so that we can test it on our end . Also , your server returns html not jsons ?